# ¿Cómo calcular el promedio de un conjunto de valores agrupados en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, tablas

Para esta cuestión:
- Apellidos y nombre de los clientes que se han gastado en la compra de canciones más que la media.

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
select customer.lastname, customer.firstname, sum(invoice.total) m
from invoice inner join customer on customer.customerId=invoice.customerId
group by customer.customerId
having sum(invoice.total) >  

select avg(sum(invoice.total))
from invoice inner join customer on customer.customerId=invoice.customerId
group by customer.customerId;
```

Pero no me funciona, no sé cómo puedo hacer el promedio de la suma de las facturas de cada cliente. He buscado sobre cómo hacer el promedio de valores resultado de otras funciones, pero no he encontrado nada. Aquí adjunto el modelo físico de la tabla:
[image: Modelo fisico Tienda musica]

Aquí está el script para generar la base de datos que uso para realizar la consulta en MySQL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lerocha/chinook-database/master/ChinookDatabase/DataSources/Chinook_MySql_AutoIncrementPKs.sql

Y aquí mi segundo intento:

```
select customer.firstname, customer.lastname
from invoice inner join customer on customer.customerId=invoice.customerId
group by 1
having sum(invoice.total) >  (select avg(cantidad)
                                    from (select customerId, sum(total) cantidad 
                                            from invoice 
                                            group by 1) t1 );
```

En el cual sigo sin entender la necesidad de darle un alias a la ultima consulta (t1).

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te piden es algo así:

```
SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM customer JOIN (
    SELECT CustomerId
      FROM invoice GROUP BY 1
      HAVING SUM(Total)>(
        SELECT AVG(total) FROM (
            SELECT CustomerId,SUM(Total) total
              FROM invoice GROUP BY 1
          ) c1  
      )  
  ) c2 USING(CustomerId);
```

### Sobre tu intento

Únicamente veo tres puntos de mejora:

- Te faltan unos paréntesis en la comparación con el promedio
- Intentas calcular el promedio total a la vez que calculas el total de cada usuario. Ten en cuenta que el promedio consiste en dividir el total de todos entre el número de usuarios y, en un `GRUOP BY`, vas a obtener tantos promedios como clientes, no un único número.
- Combinas (`JOIN`) cuando aún no te hace falta. Como tienes toda la información necesaria para tus cálculos en la tabla `invoice`, deja para el final el nombre y apellidos, con el `CustomerId` tienes información suficiente para hacer la selección que te piden.

### Sobre la forma de preguntar

- Envíanos siempre el dataset en SQL con unos registros de muestra. Lo obtienes fácilmente en phpMyAdmin con la función Exportar. En este caso he hecho lo que he podido con el esquema, pero es mucho más fácil cuando tienes la base de datos y el editor te autocompleta los nombres de campos y tablas. Además de poder comprobar los errores de sintaxis antes de enviar la solución.
- No te olvides de aportar qué esperas obtener a partir de esos datos de muestra. Además de servirnos como comprobación, resolver manualmente le problema, te ayudará a entender cómo codificar la solución. Manualmente estás haciendo un algoritmo que muy probablemente será el mismo que hará el ordenador.
- Lo más importante y lo que sí que has hecho: intentarlo. Así podremos ver qué dudas tienes y ayudarte con ellas.
- Y, por último, los mensajes de error que recibas. Eso nos ayudará a reproducir y depurar el fallo.

### 1ª pregunta: explicación de la consulta

- Recuerda que una query SQL se lee de dentro hacia afuera. Es decir, cuando le vas dando forma empiezas por operaciones sencillas que vas incrustando como subconsultas de otra más complicada. De ahí que antes de entender la compleja, haya que entender las sencillas
- La primera que tienes que visualizar es la del `GROUP BY`, que no de desoriente ese 1, simplemente indica que agrupes por el primer campo que aparezca tras el `SELECT`, en este caso `CustomerId`. Lo que conseguimos con esta primera consulta es calcular cuánto se ha gastado cada cliente.

> ```
> SELECT CustomerId,SUM(Total) total
>   FROM invoice GROUP BY 1;
> ```

- Una vez que tengas esta información, ya puedes calcular el promedio de lo que gastan todos:

> ```
> SELECT AVG(total) FROM (
>     SELECT CustomerId,SUM(Total) total
>       FROM invoice GROUP BY 1
>   ) c1;
> ```

- Y ahora sólo tienes que comparar lo que ha gastado cada uno con ese promedio que acabas de calcular:

> ```
> SELECT CustomerId,SUM(Total) total
>   FROM invoice GROUP BY 1
>   HAVING total>(
>     SELECT AVG(total) FROM (
>         SELECT CustomerId,SUM(Total) total
>           FROM invoice GROUP BY 1
>       ) c1  
>   );
> ```

- Lo que hacemos en el paso siguiente es pasar la función de totales al `HAVING` y así nos evitamos tener que meter esto en otra subconsulta intermedia para proyectar los `CustomerId`:

> ```
> SELECT CustomerId
>   FROM invoice GROUP BY 1
>   HAVING SUM(Total)>(
>     SELECT AVG(total) FROM (
>         SELECT CustomerId,SUM(Total) total
>           FROM invoice GROUP BY 1
>       ) c1  
>   );
> ```

- Y por fin llegamos al `JOIN` por el que preguntabas. Ahora que sabemos los `CustomerId` sólo hay que combinarlos con los datos que tenemos en la tabla de clientes, llegando a la consulta que tienes al principio de la respuesta.

### 2ª pregunta: exportar SQL y mensajes de error

- Probablemente en tu máquina virtual tengas instalado el Apache junto con el MySQL. Accede a http://localhost/phpmyadmin y te encontrarás con un cliente web del MySQL similar al Workbench. Ambos tienen que tener la opción de exporar la base de datos a SQL.
- Efectivamente, el SQL no da error hasta que envía la consulta completa al servidor. Ése es el error con el que debes documentar la pregunta. Aunque, como una query en SQL se va componiendo a trozos, puedes ir probándolas gradualmente. Empieza por la pequeñas, que son más fáciles de depurar.

### 3ª pregunta: tu nuevo intento

- Hasta que no modifiques la pregunta añadiendo el dataset, va a ser complicado que pueda detectar dónde está el fallo. Es mucho más cómodo probarla e ir haciéndole cambios. Y, ahora que le probado, da el mismo resultado que la mía. Enhorabuena, si te has equivocado ha sido en lo mismo que yo.

### 4ª pregunta: los alias

Quédate con la siguiente regla:

- las subconsultas en el `FROM () c1`, SIEMPRE con alias
- las subconsultas en el `WHERE total>()`, NUNCA con alias

El alias al que tú has llamado `t1` es el correspondiente al de mi segundo paso, que incluye al primero después del `FROM` y llamo `c1`. Como va después del `FROM` siempre alias, no te líes. La idea es que cuando utilizas una subconsulta después de un `FROM` deberías poder referirte a ella como si de una tabla se tratara. ¿Y cómo podrías referirte a una tabla sin nombre? No podrías, por eso es obligatorio darle un alias. Sin embargo, tras el `WHERE`, hace la función de un simple número al que no hay necesidad de mencionar. En un caso nos referimos a una tabla y en el otro a un número, ¿lo ves mejor así?

Comment: Pues resulta que me retorna 22 clientes de los 59 totales, asi que supongo que estará bien. ¿podrías explicarme la lógica de ese codigo si eres tan amable? desconozco el uso del "join" seguido de "(select...) y tampoco entiendo el "group by 1". El "using" tampoco lo he usado nunca. Perdon por mi ignorancia.

Comment: No hay nada que perdonar, preguntando me ayudas a explicarla mejor :) Voy respondiendo y me vas repreguntando, ¿ok?

Comment: Perfecto! Mil gracias por responder!

Comment: Ahí te van unas cuantas aclaraciones, pregúntame y continuamos ampliando

Comment: Voy a reintentar hacerlo siguiendo tu explicacion, que ya he leido, pero hasta que no me pongo sobre el teclado a escribir no termino de asegurarme si lo he entendido. Muchisimas gracias por esmerarte tanto en tu explicación.

PD: lo de exportar el dataset no sabia hacerlo, estoy usando una maquina virtual, que es donde tengo instalado el workbench y el MySQL

Comment: Creo que la clave para entender este caso es darle el alias a la funcion de la suma para despues poderla referenciar en el promedio.

Comment: Puedes ir ampliando tu pregunta con todas estas cuestiones y los fragmentos de código y yo haré lo mismo con la respuesta. Puedes usar los comentarios para avisarme de los cambios.

Comment: Ya lo tienes, puedes ir pasando los comentarios a la pregunta, utilizando los mismos apartados que en la respuesta para facilitar su localización, y eliminando los comentarios de aquí. Así quedará todo perfectamente documentado para que otra persona con las misma dudas pueda resolverlas.

Comment: he puesto el link de donde cogí para crear la base de datos y realizar la consulta que comento, no se si es eso lo que necesitas, acabo de entrar en un dual de desarrollo de app multiplataforma y aún ando verde con algunos conceptos. Con mi código hay dos clientes diferentes al tuyo, y debería salir igual, no termino de darte la lata jaja

Comment: Perfecto, ya he podido reproducir el problema. Ya tienes la respuesta ampliada. Ahora que ya sabes cómo preguntar, intenta sacar más información de esa base de datos y, si te trabas, pide ayuda, verás que enseguida le pillas el tranquillo. ¿Dónde estudias esto?

Comment: En Clara del Rey (Madrid).
Lo del alias ya lo entendí. Madre mia, mil gracias de verdad, por tu tiempo y tu paciencia.